# Spring Transaction annotation on junit with Spring jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa, junit4, spring-transactions

why is @Transactional required for a test case whose function will do a update (JPA repository) in dao layer like

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void processTestSuccess() throws Exception{
    abc.process();//abc instance of Abc class
}

public class Abc{
   @Transactional
   public void process(){
      .....
      jpaRepository.update(10); // spring jpa repo updating something
   }
}
```

As when test is run without @Transaction annotation on it gives the following exception at line

```
jpa.update(10);
```

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing
>   an update/delete query; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
>   update/delete query

Comment: how are you creating "abc" object in your test?

Comment: It is autowired through spring dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

Your method `process()` is annotated with `@Transactional`. This means it requires a transaction.

Since you seem to run this in an Spring application context the annotation is evaluated and an exception thrown if now transaction is available.

By adding `@Transactional` to the test you make a transaction available (which will be rolled back at the end of the test).

Comment: My question is why to annotate the Test method with @ transactional when I already know that my process method is already annotated with @ transactional since the update is happening only in process method.

Comment: As I described in my answer the annotation does different things on a test method or class vs on a bean method.